# MySQL 5.1 Slow SHOW DATABASES (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: linux, mysql, sql, query

We have about 200 databases and since upgrading from `4.1` to `5.1` we've noticed that `PHPMyAdmin` takes a while to load the left navigation sometimes. Is there anything we can do to make this quicker?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the query execute time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just migrated a site from 5.0 to 5.1 which uses some quite complex queries. queries which took <2 seconds in 5.0 are taking up to 2 mins in 5.1

I would suggest rolling back to 5.0 - that's what I am doing! - or at least test it on another machine to verify before making the change on the server.